# Positioning turtles based on links

Tags: netlogo

As part of my college assignment, I've created a scale free network  (based on Barabasi-Albert model). Each turtle represents a node and a link between turtles represent an edge. (Basically turtle-set gives nodes and link-set gives edges).

For each turtle I set the position randomly with `setxy random-xcor random-ycor`. This however causes a problem since lines representing links overlap and the whole thing looks messy.

Is there any way to position turtles such that links (or at least majority of the links)don't overlap? (I think it should be possible since the network is a hub and spore type).

Comment: If you open any of the network models in the NetLogo Model Library (File menu item), you will see how they do it. There are several different `layout` options documented in the NetLogo Dictionary, accessible through the help menu.

Comment: @JenB Thanks. The layout procedure in preferential attachment model helped